# How can I update a specific variable in EJS?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, ejs

author-home.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Author - Home Page</title>

  <link href="/css/author-home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

  <%- include('./partials/header') %>

  <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
  <button onclick="createNewDraft()">Create new draft</button>

  <h3>Draft Articles</h3>

  <div class="draft-container">
    <div>Title</div>s
    <div>Subtitle</div>
    <div>Created</div>
    <div>Last Modified</div>
    <div>Actions</div>
    <div>work</div>
  </div>

  <h3>Published Articles</h3>

</body>

</html>
```

header.ejs

```
<h1>
  <%= blogTitle %>

</h1>
<h2>
  <%= blogSubtitle %>
</h2>

<h3>
  <%= authorName %>
</h3>
```

author.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const assert = require('assert');

let blogHeader = {};

const fetchHeaderData = (callback) => {
    global.db.all(`SELECT blog.title, blog.subtitle, author.name AS author_name
        FROM
            blog
        JOIN
            author ON blog.author_id = author.author_id;`,
        function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                blogHeader = {
                    blogTitle:rows[0].title,
                    blogSubtitle:rows[0].subtitle,
                    authorName:rows[0].author_name
                }
                callback(blogHeader);
            }
    });
}

router.get("./partials/header", (req, res) => {
    fetchHeaderData((data) => {
        res.render("./partials/header", data);
    });
});

router.get("/author-home", (req, res) => {
    fetchHeaderData((data) => {
        res.render("author-home", data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the router, if I don't put data in author-home the code can't run. Can I separate the update of a specific variable? Otherwise I have to query everything from database again. The header will be repeated. The only way I could find is static partial or only exists in the EJS part. I cannot find a way to update it in Express. I was expecting header route to update the header, author-home to update the author-home so there's no need to call the variable existing in the header.